# How to access multiindex levels in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to work out the mean of each individual column "One" and "Two".

This is the result of a df.columns statement on my dataframe:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Growth %'], ['One', 'Two']],
       labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
       names=[None, 'Years'])
```

I basically want to work out the mean for all numerical values held in the "One" and "Two" columns.

If I do:

```
df.mean(axis=0)
```

I get:

```
Years
Growth %   One 17.215293

           Two 45.213257

dtype: float64
```

But I only want the individual values for these columns so I can add them to the dataframe.

I have tried doing:

```
df.mean(levels=[['Growth %'], ['One']])
```

along with similiar variations but I can't get it to show the mean of those individual columns.

Any help great appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a sample of the df you are working with? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here's what I used to re-construct:

```
In [17]: index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Growth %'], ['One', 'Two']], labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]], names=[None, 'Years'])

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,6), index=index)

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
                       0         1         2         3         4         5
         Years                                                            
Growth % One    0.449989  0.008239 -0.212202 -1.829215  0.609796  0.922987
         Two   -0.819815  0.726769  0.150591  1.851841 -0.639491 -0.637081

In [26]: df.mean(axis=1)
Out[26]: 
          Years
Growth %  One     -0.008401
          Two      0.105469
dtype: float64
```

That, what was just returned is a `pd.Series`, you can use the right index to fetch the right data.

Try this:

```
df.mean(axis=1)['Growth %']['One']
df.mean(axis=1)['Growth %']['Two']
```

I hope this helps!